# Form errors assertion in unit tests

Tags: django, django-forms, django-testing

I have a series of tests matching this pattern:

```
def test_eek(self):
    form_data = { ... }
    response = self.client.post(reverse('ook'), form_data)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200, response)
    ...
```

Where I have the form_data as valid form data.  Or so I think until I change the model and the test breaks in unexpected ways because the form was not populated correctly.

How can I assert something like:

```
self.assertTrue(not form.errors, form.errors)
```

So I get to see that whatever I passed as `form_data` is correct and if not see *what fields are fubar*.

Comment: Why not have a function that creates the properly filled-in form data? Then you can test that separately, and update it in one place when the model changes. Your other tests then just call this one tested function to get valid data.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Because i want to test the behaviour of the form with different inputs, not the same ones all the time.

Comment: Shouldn't that be part of the form test, rather than of the client?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Form test?... Tell me more... I think you hit something that I either missed or that is not clear in the documentation.  Yes, I am a Django n00b! ^_~

Comment: You can separate the form into an actual `models.ModelForm` class and test it separately - see e.g. http://test-driven-django-development.readthedocs.org/en/latest/05-forms.html